# Executing a fetch request inside prepareForDeletion not allowed?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

This is as much a question as it is a warning; I had a bug in my app which I finally tracked down to the following: inside `prepareForDeletion` of some `NSManagedObject` subclass I was accessing an array which was created on demand by executing a fetch request. If that array was already there when `prepareForDeletion` was called (and hence when no fetch request was necessary) everything worked fine, but if the array had not yet been loaded and the fetch request was executed, it seemed that the delete of the object-about-to-be-deleted was actually completed when the fetch was executed, making it impossible for `prepareForDeletion` to complete its task. I couldn't find anybody else complaining about this, however, nor any mention of it in the documentation, so perhaps it's something else. I'm curious if somebody else has seen this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this behaviour of executing fetch request in prepareForDeletion. It is frustrating why it happens. And also I found that prepareForDeletion will be called twice. First time when deleteObject: is called. Second time is when save operation is performed.

Comment: Is this a question or an answer?

Comment: Is also a question... looks like this question is 1 and a half years old.. still looking for explanations.